# how to handle more then one init.gradle file

Tags: gradle

In [Gradle 2.0 documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) 
there are some options to provide the 'init.gradle' file

1. command-line
2. init.gradle file in USER_HOME/.gradle/ folder
3. init.gradle file in USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/ folder
4. init.gradle file in USER_HOME/init.d/ folder

and 'If more than one init script is found they will all be executed'.

My use case is that we have some project that uses old Gradle version(1.7) and the syntax is not supported in Gradle 2.0 for example.

We usually provide repos info in the init.gradle file.

How can I **provide only one init.gradle** file to my project build?

Or how to **disable execution of all init.gradle** files (and I will provide all the given parameters inside my build file)?

Comment: found a workaround `gradle -I local-init.gradle -g=NOT-USER-DEFAULT-PATH . it's seem to work, the downside of that is that you will have to download all the artifacts again...

Comment: Do You have all the `init.gradle` files filled? You may leave the files empty..

Comment: currently i have only one init.gradle file fill with unsupported syntax of Gradle2.0